# Image upload in iPad ios6

Tags: ipad, ios6

Ok, this is weird.
I have a page, to upload an image. I want to use an iPad, and take a picture with the camera.

I’m submitting it to an aspx page. All I’m doing (for testing purposes), is saving the image to the server, and writing it back out to the browser, using:
You uploaded:

Everything works great, in low light conditions (dark pictures). As soon as I moved out of the office, and into standard light, the app breaks.

Sounds stupid, I know.

I’m guessing this has something to do with image size. Also, the ipad will upload the image to the server (I see it come across, and is saved to the filesystem). However, the ipad never waits for the response back from the server. It just displays a blank page after the image upload is sent.

It’s like the image is being uploaded in the background, but the ipad won’t wait for the responding text from the server.

Does that sound familiar to anyone? Got any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Fyi…got around this by posting the image to an IFrame, and then having the main page query for the uploaded image via javascript.

Still have no idea why the original problem is there, as I can duplicate the scenario. Oh well, just posting the answer in case anyone else runs into this.